# Failing commands kill the current tmux pane

Tags: shell, tmux

I recently changed linux distros and the default behavior of tmux changed: previously, failing commands had no effect on the current pane/window. Now every command that exits with a status other than zero kills the current pane. Which is kind of painful to deal with (creating a new pane or restarting the session). Is there a configuration that controls this that I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean a failing command you run directly in a pane? Or a failing command you run in a *shell* in a pane? If the latter, does the output of `printf '%s\n' "$-"` contain `e`? Does `set +e` help?

Comment: Failing commands ran in a shell in a pane. Yes the output of that command contains an `e` and issuing `set +e` helps. Is there a way to make this a default ?

Comment: Normally this is the default. Remove `set -e` from startup scripts your shell sources. What is your shell?

Comment: Turns out I had added a new config script where the IDE I used to type it, automatically added a header `set -euo pipefail`. Removing that and reloading the session fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your insight. If you reword your comment into an answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: No time now for a high quality answer. [You do it](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) if you want. I won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

As [Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski) pointed out in the comments, a shell configuration `set -e` option somehow creeped into my shell session configuration and basically caused any shell command that exits with anything other than zero to kill the shell process and by extension the underlying tmux pane. Removing that option fixes the problem.